# I have been given this drink as gift, but I don't know what it is?

Tags: alcohol

[image][image]

Can anyone please tell me what this drink is?

Comment: It tastes sour and watery, and smells like vinegar.

Comment: [same question (answered)](https://www.reddit.com/r/korea/comments/8mgkt1/my_boyfriend_bought_this_liquor_in_korea_and_cant/). Should we trust the source?

Comment: @user3664452 The Reddit post looks like an empty bottle held by a female; OP’s has contents and [appears to be] held by a male :)

Comment: @Oliver I didn't want to question the OP. I meant: can I use Reddit as a reliable source for my answer? (Incidentally, from the answer by farmersteve I guess that, at least in this case, Reddit was a reliable source)

Answer (score 4):

Oh-Bal-Ju is liquor from N.Korea. (of course you can buy in S.Korea)

It is made with 9 traditional Korean medicinal herb.

OH means crow, Bal means hair, Ju means liquor - If you drink this, you can live long as crow and white hair will change to black.

You can see a picture of it here [North Korean DMZ store](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-korean-demilitarized-zone-dmz-146547979.html)